# Auto-measuring box ARCore with Point clouds

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, arcore, measure

Is there anyway you can detect object with only ARCore and from that extract point clouds so I could measure the object with AR?

At the moment I have that I scan the object and calculate the difference from point clouds (x, y and z). But ARCore gives a lot of the time wrong point clouds and then I get faulty result.

Comment: Hi, did you resolve this issue? please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/arcore-ml-sample) to get the detections in a scene. To get the point cloud relevant to an object, you could project the points onto the image and check whether they are within the detection bounding box or not.